# Support of converting DataTableReader to List<T>

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an old'ish DAL using stored procedures via ADO and the SqlDataAdapter. I am trying to save a lot of time by using AutoMapper. I thought it would be straight forward to map the DataTableReader to a List. It appears the functionality was removed.moved in 3.3 and in 4.1 there is a new module, Automapper.Data, that may include the functionality. I have included the code in what I am trying to do. Would someone please let me know if this is possible and if so point to an example of use.

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    using (var reader = dt.CreateDataReader())
        if (reader.HasRows)
            result = Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(reader);
}
return result;//<-- Result is always count 0
```

Comment: Did you initialize Automapper with the DataReaderMapper? See: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    using (var reader = dt.CreateDataReader())
        if (reader.HasRows)
            return DataReaderMapper<T>.GetRecordes(reader);
}
```

using my helper method for all your need:

```
class DataReaderMapper<YourClass>
{
    static DataReaderMapper()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new AutoMapper.Data.DataReaderMapper { YieldReturnEnabled = true });
        });

        Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, YourClass>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<YourClass> GetRecordes(IDataReader reader)
    {
        return  Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<YourClass>>(reader);
    }
}
```

Please note! the `DataReader` must stay alive until the end of the transition on the `Result` Colllection.